# Convert date imported from CSV file to normal date in excel file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date

a date from csv as yyyy.mm.dd has been export to excel file and I try vba code to format it : Sheet1.Columns(18).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" but it keeps persistent as yyyy.mm.dd, what should I do? Here is the vba code that try to do it but failed:

```
Sub FormatDates()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Columns(18) ' Assuming your dates are in column 18

    For Each cell in rng
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then  ' Skip cells already recognized as dates
            cell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" 
        Else 
            cell.Value = DateValue(cell.Value)  ' Convert from text to date
            cell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the dates showing both types. What is your local date separator? BTW, you should switch the lines in the *Else* statement.

Comment: Did you really **import** the data? Or did you just **open** the file? I suspect the latter. The unrecognized, inconvertible dates are text strings. The recognized dates may be incorrect. I believe your most robust option will be to **import** (not open) the csv file using either `Get & Transform from Text/CSV` or the legacy import wizard. Using either, you will be able to specify that date column as being in `YMD` format, and your dates will be imported properly. You can then set the formatting of the cells however you prefer. Misrecognizing dates is a common problem posted about here.

Comment: the format depends on your local (e.g. for years in need to use jjjj). format a cell as date in excel and then choose custom. You should see the syntax to use according to your local. Nevertheless, I agree with the previous comment that you don't need a macro for this. when importing the csv you can set the field formats directly or in Powerquery (when you choose "Transform").

Comment: I actually has imported data from a CSV file to excel file , the idea is that I try to automate everything so doing Get & Transform is a bit manual there. Not sure if there is some kind of function that could really help, I try DateValue ,then isDate but no result so far

Comment: let say we have many CSV file to export to excel and we have to do Get& Transform then that would be annoying isn't it. it would be more useful and effective with a click of a button and all is done

Comment: @AlanWong You can easily import either a list of CSV files or all of the CSV files and various folders using power query. Once you have it set up to your specifications, you can repeat the action with a click of a single button. Within the power query transform or edit, it would be simple to properly interpret those dates.

Answer (score 0):

`DateValue` doesn't see dots as date separators, so replace those:

```vb
    For Each cell in rng
        If Not IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            ' Convert from text to date.
            cell.Value = DateValue(Replace(cell.Value, ".", "-")) 
        End If
        cell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks Gustave, that works, it's tricky though, never thought of that, really appreciate it